# Android startActivity from child submodule

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a tutorial activity in the **app** submodule. Within the **app** manifest I have

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.TutorialActivity"
    android:exported="false"
    android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"/>
```

The **app** layer contains a **core** submodule which houses much of the re-useable business logic. I want to launch the TutorialActivity from the launcher activity contained within the **core**.

I am using the following code to set up the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TutorialActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

However Android Studio is unable to resolve the symbol "TutorialActivity". I am thinking this is because the tutorial activity exists in a different submodule layer.

Is there a way to launch an activity owned by a parent submodule from the child submodule in Android?

Thanks,
Otterman

EDIT

```
┌app
│
├─ (Android Libraries Modules)
│    │
│    ├── core
│    ├── buzz
.    .
.    .
```

Comment: you're missing closing quotes after "sensorPortrait

Comment: Sorry, a mistake making this question. It is correct in the code and edited to reflect.

Comment: Can you describe your project and folder structure within Android Studio? When you say `app` and `core` are submodules, I assume you mean that they are modules in your Android Studio project. Is that correct?

Comment: Also, what module contains `TutorialActivity`? I think it is in `app` from the way I read your question. Is that correct. It will also help a little if you include the class and method names that contain the intent creation code. This code is in the `core` module, right?

Answer (score 0):

In the `core` module, you need to add the `app` module as a dependency. In the Project pane, right click on the `core` module and select Open Module Settings from the popup menu. Click on the Dependencies tab at the top of the Project Structure dialog. On the right, click the button with the green + and select Module dependency. Finally, select the `app` module and click OK on each open dialog. Recompile.